# Should one pray for something to happen or for the strength to do it oneself?

Tags: tefilla, hashkafah-philosophy

I was wondering if it is better to pray for a solution to a problem or pray for the strength to do it oneself. I would also be happy for a link to a passing prayer or discussion. Thank you!

Comment: see psalm 62.2 with comments

Comment: @kouty Which comments are you referring to?

Comment: I am refering to the Sefer Haykarim in the 4th part I think, he says that you don't know what is good for you, so it's not right to ask a detailed request

Comment: What does "passing" mean in this context?

Comment: Why not pray for both?

Answer (score 1):

I can't point to specific sources; but while initiative is certainly important, the entire point of prayer in Judaism is recognizing that you Can't do it yourself. Of course anything one does "himself" is also only through the help of G-d, but it seems that praying for a solution that doesn't require one's strength or involvement would be the easier way to attain this mindset